# ave function in R: First argument a vector

Tags: r, average

I'm trying to use the following code in R:

```
ID=seq(1,11)
g=c(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,3)
x <- sample(11)
d <- data.frame(ID,g, x)

Ranking_Categoria<-function(d,var,category)
{
  d$rank<-ave(d$var,d$category,FUN=rank)
  return(d)
}
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Error in split.default(x, g) : first argument must be a vector.
```

Variables var and category (character) are columns of the dataframe d that user needs to specify in order to get the desired result.  I need to refer to this names when I use the function `ave()` as you can see.

Comment: Your trouble is not with `ave` but with not knowing how to pass arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[[` to get the `var` and `category` columns by name:

```
Ranking_Categoria<-function(d,var,category)
{
  d$rank<-ave(d[[var]],d[[category]],FUN=rank)
  return(d)
}
```

... because `d$var` tries to get the column called "var", and there is none.

**UPDATE**

```
> Ranking_Categoria(d, "x", "g")
   ID g  x rank
1   1 1 10    3
2   2 2  9    2
3   3 3  4    1
4   4 1 11    4
5   5 1  1    1
6   6 2  8    1
7   7 3  6    2
8   8 4  2    1
9   9 4  5    2
10 10 1  3    2
11 11 3  7    3
```

Comment: Try running it as `> Ranking_Categoria(d,"x","g")`.

Comment: @GregSnow - OK, I did, and added output to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be not to use names at all:

```
Ranking_Categoria<-function(d,var,category)
{
  d$rank<-ave(var,category,FUN=rank)
  return(d)
}
```

Then call it as

```
Ranking_Categoria(d,d$x,d$g)
```

The reason why the function in your question didn't work as you thought it would is partially because R's syntax and [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)-ness for string manipulation *sucks*.  Here's a hacky, fragile solution using [`eval`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) and [`parse`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html):

```
Ranking_Categoria<-function(d,var,category)
{  
  string=paste('d$rank<-ave(d$',var,',d$',category,',FUN=rank)',sep="")
  eval(parse(text=string))
  return(d)
}
```

However, you still have to call it as

```
Ranking_Categoria(d,"x","g")
```

And if you already have objects with the names of `x` and `g`, then may the gods help you if you try to do `Ranking_Categoria(d,x,g)`...  Crap like this is why I've gone from using Perl and R equally to sticking with Perl (my first and native programming language) and using R only when necessary.

Comment: It is not that "$" should not be used in functions, but that "$" is a shortcut for "[[" that does not require quoting, and therefore is not evaluated.  The same thing happens outside of functions.

Comment: (For anyone that is listening, Greg knows more R/S than I will ever know.) "$" cannot be used to accept arguments that get passed to functions. Its use needs to be restricted to accessing fixed names. For the newbie it will be easier to remember that `obj[[name]]` will work and that obj$name will often fail when using inside functions.

Comment: @GregSnow - Yeah, that's what I tried to say in my answer. `$` has another quirk that is dangerous though: It does partial matching!